# Int Value in a TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I wrote this textformfield for userdata

```
TextFormField(
                    initialValue: datiUtente.peso.toString(),
                    validator: (val) =>
                        val.isEmpty ? 'inserisci il tuo peso' : null,
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentPeso = val),
                  ),
```

For name ed surname is ok, but if I want to use this for an int value how can I do it? I tried to like this but doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the number as keyboardType for the TextField using:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number
```

And your field code look like below,

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter your number"),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
         FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
    ], // Only numbers can be entered
    validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'inserisci il tuo peso' : null,
    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentPeso = val),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the keyboardType as in `TextInputType.number` TextFormField:-  keyboardType: TextInputType.number